# How do jQuery Mobile widgets work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile to develop a mobile web app for the first time. It is easy to get jQuery Mobile started with just adding some data-* attributes. So far, it is good. However, I was always troubled with one question: How do jQuery Mobile widgets work with just add some data-* attributes instead of invoking the widget explicitly just like jQuery UI widget? When and where do they get invoked and then rendered as they look like? I've searched google all over but found nothing valuable. Anyone could help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a feature of jquery-mobile called auto-initialization. It scans the dom when the page is loaded and based on the attributes of the html elements, it automatically calls the invocation functions on each of the elements. It's pretty simple actually. You can read more about this behavior here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html